# Free type variables in Hindley-Milner type inference

Tags: type-theory, type-systems, type-inference

I'm trying to understand how generalization works in H-M type inference. In order to generalize a function, we:

- Collect all the free type variables in the type of the function body,
- Subtract away any type variables that appear free in the type environment,
- And whatever is leftover can be generalized into a type scheme

The middle bullet is the one I'm having trouble with. In particular, I don't understand how it's possible for there to be any free type variables in the type environment. When we create a type scheme, we close over its free type variables, so the resulting scheme shouldn't have any free type variables. Thus, since none of the schemes in a type environment should have free type variables, how could the type environment itself have any free type variables?

Perhaps someone could give me a simple example program in OCaml or Haskell in which the type environment has a free type variable during type inference?

Comment: I am not sure what you're asking, but perhaps it would help to think about nested functions: `fun x -> .... (fun y -> e) ....`. If the type of `x` appears in `e`, will you generalize over it?

Comment: Generalization only occurs for `let` expressions, but I think you're probably right that inference of a nested `let` could encounter free type variables in the type environment. I will investigate that. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, `let` is the thing to look at, not functions. You lead me astray when you wrote "In order to generalize a function, we ..." :-)

Answer (score 2):

I found a good explanation and example in a paper called "[Let Should not be Generalised](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/tldi10-vytiniotis.pdf)":

> A central feature of the Hindley-Milner system is that let-bound definitions are generalised. For example, consider the slightly artificial definition:

> `let f x = let g y = (x,y) in ...`

> The definition for `g` is typed in an environment in which `x :: a`, and the inferred type for `g` is `∀b.b → (a, b)`. This type is
> polymorphic in `b`, but not in `a`, because the latter is free in the
> type environment at the definition of `g`. This side condition, that `g`
> should be **generalised only over variables that are not free in the
> type environment**, is the only tricky point in the entire Hindley-Milner type system.